# EF core won't map inherited types in a Table-per-hierarchy and discriminator configuration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I have a base class with some properties and 10 derived types, 2 of them have a navigation property to another table, both of them are configured the same way, one is working and the other is not.

```
    public abstract class StepBase : FullAuditedEntity<Guid>
    { 
        public StepType StepType { get; set; }
        public bool IsDone { get; protected set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class TimerStep : StepBase
    {
      
        public string Label { get; set; }
        **public UpdateField UpdateField { get; set; }**
```

```
    public class UpdateStep : StepBase
    {
        public UpdateField UpdateField { get; set; }
    }
```

```
        builder.Entity<StepBase>(b =>
        {
            //Configure table & schema name
            b.ConfigureBaseEntityProperties(tableName: "Steps");

            //Properties
            b.Property(p => p.Title).HasMaxLength(100).IsUnicode(false).IsUnicode(false).IsRequired();
            b.Property(p => p.Order).IsRequired(true);
            b.Property(p => p.IsDone).HasDefaultValue(false);
            b.Property(p => p.Description).HasMaxLength(2048).IsUnicode(false);
            b.HasMany(p => p.SubSteps).WithOne();
            b.HasDiscriminator(p => p.StepType)
            .HasValue<ChangePCountStep>(StepType.ChangePCount)
            .HasValue<ExperimentStep>(StepType.Experiment)
            .HasValue<GeneticModificationStep>(StepType.GeneticModification)
            .HasValue<MyOwnStep>(StepType.MyOwn)
            .HasValue<StartDateStep>(StepType.StartDate)
            .HasValue<StoredSampleStep>(StepType.StoredSample)
            .HasValue<TimerStep>(StepType.Timer)
            .HasValue<TreatmentStep>(StepType.Treatment)
            .HasValue<UpdateStep>(StepType.Update)
            .HasValue<DestinationVesselStep>(StepType.DestinationVessel);

        });
```

```
    private static void ConfigureTimerStep(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<TimerStep>(b =>
        {
            //Properties
            b.Property(p => p.Label).HasMaxLength(256).IsUnicode(false).IsRequired(false);
            b.Property(p => p.StartDate).IsRequired();
            b.Property(p => p.ReleaseIn).IsRequired();
            b.Property(p => p.ReleaseInTimeLapse).IsRequired();
            b.HasOne(a => a.UpdateField)
             .WithOne(b => (TimerStep)b.Step)
             .HasForeignKey<UpdateField>(b => b.StepId);
        });
    }
```

```
    private static void ConfigureUpdateField(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<UpdateField>(b =>
        {
            //Configure table & schema name
            b.ConfigureBaseEntityProperties(tableName: "UpdateField");
            //Properties
            b.Property(p => p.UpdatedDate).IsRequired();
            b.Property(p => p.UpdateType).IsRequired();
            b.Property(p => p.Field).HasMaxLength(2048).IsUnicode(false).IsRequired();
        });
    }
```

```
    private static void ConfigureUpdateStep(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<UpdateStep>(b =>
        {
            //Properties
            b.HasOne(a => a.UpdateField)
                .WithOne(b => (UpdateStep)b.Step)
                .HasForeignKey<UpdateField>(b => b.StepId);
        });
    }
```

UpdateStep is the one working fine and TimerStep is not, when I try to insert one it throws a
---- Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException : SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'.

the insert method are excactly the same also

```
            TimerStep step = new(newId)
            {
                ReleaseInTimeLapse = input.ReleaseInTimeLapse,
                StartDate = input.StartDate,
                Label = input.Label,
                ReleaseIn = input.ReleaseIn,
                UpdateField = new(GuidGenerator.Create())
                {
                    Field = input.UpdateField.Field,
                    UpdateType = input.UpdateField.UpdateType,
                    UpdatedDate = input.UpdateField.UpdatedDate,
                },
            };
```

```
            UpdateStep step = new(GuidGenerator.Create())
            {
                UpdateField = new(GuidGenerator.Create())
                {
                    Field = input.Field,
                    UpdateType = input.UpdateType,
                    UpdatedDate = input.UpdatedDate,
                }
            };
```

Both the entities should be working the same way

Comment: Where are you setting the StepID?  What is the GUID being given to the step ID that inserts successfully?   Maybe it's default (all zeros).

Comment: The StepId on UpdateField should't be set automatically by EF core?